# Smart way to transform stm32 function into class

Tags: c++, gcc, embedded, stm32

I'm trying to build a class for stm32 peripheral function like i2c, uart. But I ran into some situation where I don't know what to do is the best way.

Below is my I2C init function:

```
void init_I2C1(void)
{
    /* RCC initialization */
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1, ENABLE);

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {
        .GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7,
        .GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF,
        .GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz,
        .GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP,
        .GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP
    };
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_I2C1);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_I2C1);

    I2C_InitTypeDef I2C_InitStruct = {
        .I2C_ClockSpeed = 100000,
        .I2C_Mode = I2C_Mode_I2C,
        .I2C_DutyCycle = I2C_DutyCycle_2,
        .I2C_OwnAddress1 = 0x75,
        .I2C_Ack = I2C_Ack_Enable,
        .I2C_AcknowledgedAddress = I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit
    };
    I2C_Init(I2C1, &I2C_InitStruct);

    I2C_Cmd(I2C1, ENABLE);
}
```

But There is 3 pair of I2C that I can use, so I want to write a general class so I can just specify the number to the class instead of wirte 3 similar functions.

Therefore, I need to find a way to replace those constants.
For those constant just represent a continuous value, I can just use bit shift operation.

ex.

```
#define GPIO_PinSource6            ((uint8_t)0x06)
#define GPIO_PinSource7            ((uint8_t)0x07)
```

But other constants are complicated. They are pointers of some structure, so I cannot just just bit shift them. And there are not array either so I also cannot use an interger to go through.

ex.

```
#define PERIPH_BASE           ((uint32_t)0x40000000)
#define APB1PERIPH_BASE       PERIPH_BASE

#define I2C1_BASE             (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x5400)
#define I2C2_BASE             (APB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x5800)

#define I2C1                ((I2C_TypeDef *) I2C1_BASE)  //the constant I need to use
#define I2C2                ((I2C_TypeDef *) I2C2_BASE)  //the constant I need to use
```

The solution I have now is to trace back to the numerical value then do the bit shifting thing.For example,

```
I2C_TypeDef * I2C_Type_Ptr = (I2C_TypeDef *)(APB1PERIPH_BASE + (0x5400 << i2c_number));
I2C_Init(I2C_Type_Ptr, &I2C_InitStruct);
```

But it looks ugly and stupid. I wonder whether there is a more efficient way to do this.

Here is the whole code of the class I have done so far.

```
//Just for I2C1 & I2C2, there all use portB
I2C::I2C(uint8_t number, uint8_t port_SCL, uint8_t port_SDA)
{
    /* RCC initialization */
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd((RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1 << (number - 1)), ENABLE);

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {
        .GPIO_Pin = (GPIO_Pin_0 << port_SCL) | (GPIO_Pin_0 << port_SDA),
        .GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF,
        .GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz,
        .GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP,
        .GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP
    };
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, (GPIO_PinSource0 + port_SCL), GPIO_AF_I2C1);  //all I2C AF selection are all the same (0x04)
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, (GPIO_PinSource0 + port_SDA), GPIO_AF_I2C1);

    I2C_InitTypeDef I2C_InitStruct = {
        .I2C_ClockSpeed = 100000,
        .I2C_Mode = I2C_Mode_I2C,
        .I2C_DutyCycle = I2C_DutyCycle_2,
        .I2C_OwnAddress1 = 0x75,
        .I2C_Ack = I2C_Ack_Enable,
        .I2C_AcknowledgedAddress = I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit
    };
    I2C_TypeDef * I2C_Type_Ptr = (I2C_TypeDef *)(APB1PERIPH_BASE + (0x5400 << number));
    I2C_Init(I2C_Type_Ptr, &I2C_InitStruct);

    I2C_Cmd(I2C_Type_Ptr, ENABLE);
}
```

Thank you for your help~~

(P.S. The library I use is "STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver")

Comment: I think the first step here is to ditch the ST libs with all the questionable structs and questionable struct casts. When writing a class for a hardware peripheral, there is no obvious need to make the hardware registers part of the class. In fact what you have here is a brittle "singleton" instead of a proper class. What if the MCU contain multiple I2C peripherals? Instead, write something based on offsets of the first address in each hardware peripheral. Make definitions like `#define I2C_1 (*(volatile uint32_t*)0x12345678u)` then pass that along to the init function/constructor.

Comment: Don't do it. You will spend endless hours writing super abstract code. You can find many STM32 C++ libraries on github. Just write the abstractions that _you_ need for your specific tasks, and be done with it. https://github.com/andysworkshop/stm32plus/blob/master/lib/include/i2c/f1%2Cf4/I2C.h#L57 https://github.com/msemegen/CML/blob/master/lib/soc/m4/stm32l4/peripherals/I2C.hpp#L158

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried about hiding the ST libraries completely, then you could just use the `I2C_TypeDef *` like so:

```cpp
I2C::I2C(I2C_TypeDef*, uint8_t port_SCL, uint8_t port_SDA)
```

Ohterwise, I would just write a function like the below:

```cpp
I2C_TypeDef* getI2CTypeDef(uint8_t instance)
{
    switch (instance) {
        case 1U:
            return I2C1;
        case 2U:
            return I2C2;
        case 3U:
            return I2C3;
    }

    return I2C1;
}
```

A couple of observations not directly related to your question:

1. Instead of using a plain `uint8_t` for the I2C instance, use an `enum class`. This will give you a better type safety.
2. StdPeriph driver is no longer supported. If you care about portability to newer chips, better switch to HAL now.

Comment: One has not been able to buy newer STM32 chips in the past one and a half year, so if one is "stuck" in an older version, that's probably a blessing, since with some luck parts may still be available. If they keep this up much longer, STM32 will end up blacklisted in all new designs and then we all have to port to another MCU family anyhow.